# How to copy only formatted cells into rows with column name in vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy only formatted cells from one sheet to another into row wise with their column name from vba in excel

Comment: What do you mean by formatted?  Use of any or all of NumberFormat, HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAligment, Vertical Text, Wrap Text, Shrink to fit, Merge Cells, Bold, Italic, Underline Single, Underline Double, etc, etc?

Comment: It may be bold or coloured or cell is filled with any colour

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been down voted because it does not conform to the rules of this site.  In the top bar to the left of the search box is [help].  I think viewing both the Tour and the Help Centre will assist you in asking questions that are welcome here.

The major problems with your question are: (1) it is vague, (2) you show no effort in trying to solve the problem yourself and (3) it sounds as though you want someone to code a macro for you.

I am going to assume your big problem is you do not know how to determine if a cell has a non-default format.  If you had searched for “excel vba bold text” you would have found some pages that provide useful background.  Try to narrow your questions down to a single issue and it is usually easy to find some relevant help.

The macro below should be copied into a new workbook.  It formats some cells and then displays those formats in the Immediate Window.  Work through that macro line by line and study how I set and determined the format of each cell.  But first some background.

A cell can only have one interior or background colour.  It cannot be half red and half blue.  You can set or read the interior colour with cell properties `.Interior.Color` and `.Interior.ColorIndex`.  I demonstrate how to set with `ColorIndex` and read with either.

A cell can be mixed bold.  That is: part of the text can be bold and part not bold.  I demonstrate how to set the entire text bold and how to set the first four characters of the text bold.  When I check the cell’s bold status, you will see that I use `IsNull` to check for mixed status before I check for being all bold.  This sequence is important.  Try the other way round if you want to know why.

Like bold, the font colour can be mixed.  Like background colour, you can be set and read it with either `.Font.Color` or `.Font.ColorIndex`.

I hope this gets you started.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet
  Dim WshtDest As Worksheet

  Set WshtSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")        ' Source worksheet
  Set WshtDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")       ' Destination worksheet

  With WshtSrc

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete

    ' Format selected cells in the range A1:C4

    With .Cells(1, 1)
      .Value = "Cell A1"
    End With
    With .Cells(1, 2)
      .Value = "Cell B1"
      .Font.Bold = False
    End With
    With .Cells(1, 3)
      .Value = "Cell C1"
      .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    With .Cells(1, 4)
      .Value = "Cell D1"
      .Characters(1, 4).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With .Cells(2, 1)
      .Value = "Cell A2"
    End With
    With .Cells(2, 2)
      .Value = "Cell B2"
      .Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With .Cells(2, 3)
      .Value = "Cell C2"
      .Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
    With .Cells(2, 4)
      .Value = "Cell D2"
      .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End With

    With .Cells(3, 1)
      .Value = "Cell A3"
    End With
    With .Cells(3, 2)
      .Value = "Cell B3"
      .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
    With .Cells(3, 3)
      .Value = "Cell C3"
      .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
    With .Cells(3, 4)
      .Value = "Cell D3"
      .Characters(1, 4).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End With

    For RowCrnt = 1 To 3
      For ColCrnt = 1 To 4
        Debug.Print "Cell " & ColNumToCode(ColCrnt) & RowCrnt & " is ";

        If IsNull(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Font.Bold) Then
          Debug.Print "mixed bold font";
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Font.Bold = True Then
          Debug.Print "bold font";
        Else
          Debug.Print "not bold font";
        End If

        Debug.Print ", ";

        If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
          Debug.Print "Interior colour index=None (background white)";
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Then
          Debug.Print "Interior colour index=Automatic (background white)";
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
          Debug.Print "Interior colour index=2 (background white)";
        Else
          Debug.Print "Interior colour index=" & .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex & " (background not white";
        End If

        Debug.Print ", ";

        If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
          Debug.Print "Interior colour number=" & .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.Color & " (background white)";
        Else
          Debug.Print "Interior colour number=" & .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Interior.Color & " (background not white)";
        End If

        Debug.Print " and ";

        If IsNull(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Font.Color) Then
          Debug.Print "font colour mixed";
        ElseIf .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
          Debug.Print "font black";
        Else
          Debug.Print "font not black (Font colour number=" & .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Font.Color & ")";
        End If

        Debug.Print

      Next
    Next

  End With

End Sub
Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim ColCode As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = ColCode

End Function
```